# the terminal command keeps saying cannot execute binary file

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

```
Pursotams-iMac:~ Pursotam$ /Users/Pursotam/Downloads/Microsoft\ Office\ 2016\ v15.12.3/Patch.dmg 
-bash: /Users/Pursotam/Downloads/Microsoft Office 2016 v15.12.3/Patch.dmg: cannot execute binary file
Pursotams-iMac:~ Pursotam$
```

This is my problem. can someone help please?

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access a **disk image** directly like this

You can use **hdiutil** built in mac that allows disk images to be mounted directly from terminal

Use the following command to mount it

```
hdiutil attach /path/to/disk/image.dmg
```

Once attached find the mount point using the command below

```
diskutil list
```

It should output something like below

```
/dev/disk1 Apple_partition_scheme
/dev/disk1s1 Apple_partition_map
/dev/disk1s2 Apple_HFS /Volumes/Mounted Disk Image
```

Now you should be able to call disk contents using

```
sudo installer /Volumes/Mounted\ Disk\ Image/diskimagecontent.pkg
```

Answer (score 2):

A disk image (`.dmg`) is not an executable file; it simply contains files. You'll need to *open* or *mount* the image in order to see the files inside it (and execute them).